# Show alert message on click of home button in iPhone

Tags: iphone, uialertview

In Iphone I have to show an alert if the user clicks on home button immediately to indicate him that "The process will be stopped and he will loose the data".I have to tried to implement this using applicationWillResignActive and applicationDidEnterBackground.Can any one help  me how can i achieve this?Is it appropriate to show such alert message on home button

Thanks,
Yogesh Chaudhari

Comment: Apple will probably reject your app for this, it creates bad user experience. Just serialize data and deserialize when user gets back

Comment: No its not possible in iOS devices..

Comment: It's not possible. See here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4489890/can-i-cancel-the-method-applicationdidenterbackground

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this below code this will help you.

Its not really a way to quit the program, but a way to force people to quit.

UIAlertView *anAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Hit Home Button to Exit" message:@"Tell em why they're quiting" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
[anAlert show];

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
   if (buttonIndex == 0) 
    {
        [[NSThread mainThread] exit]
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Nikunj R. Jadav. . can you please clarify where should i put the line "UIAlertView *anAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Hit Home Button to Exit" message:@"Tell em why they're quiting" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
[anAlert show];"
I mean in which funciton. .

Comment: Home button is perform action. -(IBAction)homebutton:(id)sender

Comment: Hi  Nikunj R. Jadav. .I am taking about the default home button which is present on the iphone. .How can i add selector homebutton() to the default home button of Iphone. .

Comment: No Its a bad action perform and apple reject your apps